# How can a DateFormat parse an exact date in java (like DateTime.ParseExact in .NET)?

Tags: java, date

This question is raised by the following code:

```
DateFormat DF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String dateString = "20110133";
System.out.println(DF.parse(dateString));
// Wed Feb 02 00:00:00 CET 2011
```

The `parse` method transformed Jan 33 to Feb 02.
Is there a way to throw an Exception if the `dateString` does not represent a real date?

Just like [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) in .NET.

Comment: Modern comment: I strongly recommend that you do not use `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` any more since those classes are troublesome and long outdated. You have seen just a very slight bit of the trouble with them. Use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API (since Java 1.8, out in 2014](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: It’s simple when you know it: Use `LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)`. For your string it throws `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20110133' could not be parsed: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 33`. If he string is `20110230`, the message will be *Text '20110230' could not be parsed: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 30'*. Enjoy the precise messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try doing this

```
DF.setLenient(false);
```

[javadoc reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29)

Comment: It's not perfect and won't work in all instances, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088140/java-how-to-parse-a-date-strictly

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `setLenient(boolean)` method of the DateFormat class to tell it not to be lenient (i.e. accept and then convert) with dates that aren't valid.

Comment: Will not always work, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088140/java-how-to-parse-a-date-strictly

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6597875/10819573) uses legacy date-time API which was the correct thing to do using the standard library in 2011 when the question was asked. In March 2014, `java.time` API supplanted the [error-prone legacy date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Since then, it has been strongly recommended to use this modern date-time API.

The java.time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and for [basic format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) i.e. yyyyMMdd, it comes with a [predefined formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`.

Using this predefined formattter, try to parse your string to a `LocalDate` and `catch` the exception, if any, to understand the cause.

**Demo using java.time API**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] samples = { "20221123", "20110133", "20110131", "20110229", "20110228" };
        for (String dateString : samples) {
            try {
                System.out.println("============================");
                System.out.println(
                        dateString + " parsed to " + LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE));
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
============================
20221123 parsed to 2022-11-23
============================
Text '20110133' could not be parsed: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 33
============================
20110131 parsed to 2011-01-31
============================
Text '20110229' could not be parsed: Invalid date 'February 29' as '2011' is not a leap year
============================
20110228 parsed to 2011-02-28
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.