# SimpleDateFormat.parse() - generates wrong date for different date-formats

Tags: java, date

Below is my code to parse the date using SimpleDateFormat with pattern:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";    
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
try {
    Date date = format.parse("05-21-2030");
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can see the date which I passed to parse is different from date format which is specified in SimpleDateFormat. In this case I was expecting kind of excpetion as format is different but it parsed successfully with some different date values. I got the output - **Tue Mar 22 00:00:00 IST 12**

When I pass the same format like **2030-05-21** it works fine.

Can you guys please let me know how can I prevent such things in my code?

Comment: You have to use strict in that case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088140/java-how-to-parse-a-date-strictly

Comment: @NitinDandriyal: There is no explicit strict mode. You have to turn off leniency.

Comment: I meant strict as a general term, that's why given the link that answers appropriately

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basically you want `SimpleDateFormat` to be strict, so set lenient to false.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
format.setLenient(false);
```

Comment: Sadly setting lenient false is still lenient. "2010/01/5" is allowed for the pattern "yyyy/MM/dd". 20100901andGarbage" is allowed for the pattern "yyyyMMdd". I have made an extension of SimpleDateFormat that is strict here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014488/simpledateformat-parse-ignores-the-number-of-characters-in-pattern/19503019#19503019

Answer (score 4):

If you can afford using Java 8 time API, its formatter works as expected:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2030-05-21", formatter);
    System.out.println(date);
    LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse("05-21-2030", formatter);
    System.out.println(date2);
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
2030-05-21
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '05-21-2030' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
    at java8.Snippet.main(Snippet.java:25)
```